# Authenticating a user role in Laravel and protecting a route

Tags: authentication, laravel, roles, laravel-routing

I have taken advice from people here and given Laravel a try, I have been trying to create a user authentication system.  I am having trouble translating what I know works in PHP to Laravel using Eloquent.

What I am trying to do here is identify a user, their roles, if the user has a role of admin they can access the route /admin

I know I can use a package such as Entrust but that is not really helping me learn.

I have created Models for both User and Role.  I also have a lookup table called role_user with a user_id and role_id.

In **User.php** I have

```
public function roles(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'users_roles');

}
```

In **Role.php** I have

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_roles');
}
```

I know if I used

```
$roles = user::find(1)->roles;
return ($roles);
```

It will and does return the correct user id (1) and the roles assigned to that user.  Now what I am struggling with is how to pick out the admin role and only if the user has this will it allow access to /admin

The route should essentially be

```
Route::get('admin', function()
{

    return View::make('admin.index');

 })->before('auth');
```

What I can't figure how/where/should I check for the admin role first and how to then apply that to the auth check to only permit an admin access to the route.

Any help appreciated.

Lee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have used `auth` filter so you should check in the `auth` filter in `app/filters.php` file:

```
Route::filter('auth', function($route, $request)
{
    // Login check (Default)
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');

    // Admin check
    if(!in_array('admin', Auth::user()->roles->toArray())) {
        return Redirect::to('/'); // Redirect home page
    }

});
```

You may use a different filter, for example:

```
Route::get('admin', function()
{
    return View::make('admin.index');

})->before('isAdmin');
```

Declare the custom `isAdmin` filter in `app/filters.php`:

```
Route::filter('isAdmin', function($route, $request)
{
    if(!Auth::check()) return Redirect::guest('login');
    if( !in_array('admin', Auth::user()->roles->toArray()) ) {
        return Redirect::to('/'); // Redirect home page
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I had the right idea in the wrong place and order.

Answer (score 6):

For Laravel 5, use [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters):

*Create new middleware*

```
# php artisan make:middleware RoleMiddleware
```

*Check the user role* - redirect if invalid role

```
// app/Http/Middleware/RoleMiddleware.php

class RoleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            // Redirect...
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

*Add key in order to assign to routes* - can also make global

```
// app/Http/Kernel.php

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class, // new
];
```

*Protect the routes*

```
// app/Http/routes.php

Route::put('post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'role:editor', function ($id) {
    // routes for editor
}]);
```